# Wiring USB-C host to USB-C and USB-A receptacle

Tags: usb

I have some phones that enter a special mode when the D+ USB signal is momentarily connected to ground, and I want to make a PCB that makes it easy to enter this mode.

Some phones have USB-C, and some don't, so I was thinking to have three receptacles, one USB-C for the host, and USB-C + USB-A for the phones. I'm aware having two receptacles for the downstream device probably breaks all kinds of specifications, but I'm assuming only one is ever plugged in at a given time.

My question is mainly around power delivery, I'm a bit unsure what to do with the CC pins. Does CC1/2 even need to be connected on the phone end if the 5.1k resistors are in place on the receptacle that connects to the host?

Thanks for the help!

[image]

Comment: Why not put USB-C on both sides and use a USB-C-to-USB-A cable if needed?

Comment: @user253751 That would be simpler, true. If I implement that, would it be sufficient to just connect the CC1/CC2 lines together?

Comment: actually I suppose it would be USB-C-to-USB-micro-B and I'm not sure if that's a cable that exists. But there is USB-C-to-female-USB-A and there is USB-A-to-USB-micro-B. Only the 5V/GND/D+/D- lines will be passed through these adapters. Connect the other lines however they are supposed to be for USB-C phones